# How to convert .DXA file with ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding, video-codecs

I have .dxa video footage that I'd like to convert to a more standard format with ffmpeg. By doing research I found some people reccomend converting to .yuv first, then convert from .yuv to .mp4. (`ffmpeg -video_size 640x480 -r 25 -i meetsquid.dxa -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.yuv` ) I am able to convert from .dxa to .yuv however I think the file becomes corrupt. Once the file is yuv and I try to convert from yuv to mp4 I get a message that says something along the lines of "error input size cannot be 0X0"

is there a way to convert this file?
here is some info I got from ffprobe

```
Input #0, dxa, from 'meetsquid.dxa':
  Duration: 00:00:44.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 356 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 39, 1/10: Video: dxa, 1 reference frame, pal8, 640x480, 0/1, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
    Stream #0:1, 39, 1/11025: Audio: adpcm_ms ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 11025 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 44 kb/s
[AVIOContext @ 00000242ad489180] Statistics: 2670875 bytes read, 80 seeks
```